# NOR Queries with CaminteJS

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

I want to do a query with CaminteJS, basically just want to get a `completed` job, which `status` is neither `running` nor `queued`. Please help, thank you very much!

```js
Result.findOne()
    .where('job_id', job_id)
    .where('status').ne('running')
    .where('status').ne('queued') // looks like this line is overriding the last line
    .sort('-number')
    .run({}, callback);
```

I also tried mongoose way but still not working.

```js
    .nor([{status: 'running'}, {status: 'queued'}]) // not a caminte api
```

```js
    .where('status').nin(['running', 'queued']) // not working
```

```js
    .where('status').ne('running').ne('queued') // not working
```